# Sorting an array in Ruby (Special Case)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array in Ruby which has values as follows

```
xs = %w(2.0.0.1
2.0.0.6
2.0.1.10
2.0.1.5
2.0.0.8)
```

and so on. I want to sort the array such that the final result should be something like this :

```
ys = %w(2.0.0.1
2.0.0.6
2.0.0.8
2.0.1.5
2.0.1.10)
```

I have tried using the `array.sort` function, but it places `"2.0.1.10"` before `"2.0.1.5"`. I am not sure why that happens

Comment: Only the numbers are array elements? Or the dots are too? If you could refactor your array notation to the right one i am sure we can help you better.

Comment: The values are all strings as it contains a dot in between too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) ([Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)), and taking advantage of the [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) defined by an array of integers ([Array#<=>](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)):

```
sorted_ips = ips.sort_by { |ip| ip.split(".").map(&:to_i) }
```

> Can you please explain a bit more elaborately

1. You cannot compare strings containing numbers: `"2" > "1"`, yes, but `"11" < "2"` because strings are compared lexicographically, like words in a dictionary. Therefore, you must convert the ip into something than can be compared (array of integers): `ip.split(".").map(&:to_i)`. For example `"1.2.10.3"` is converted to `[1, 2, 10, 3]`. Let's call this transformation `f`.
2. You could now use `Enumerable#sort`: `ips.sort { |ip1, ip2| f(ip1) <=> f(ip2) }`, but  check always if the higher abstraction `Enumerable#sort_by` can be used instead. In this case: `ips.sort_by { |ip| f(ip) }`. You can read it as "take the `ips` and sort them by the order defined by the `f` mapping".

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more elaborately

Answer (score 1):

Split your data into chunks by splitting on `'.'`. There is no standard function to do it as such so you need to write a custom sort to perform this.

And the behaviour you said about `2.0.1.10` before `2.0.1.5` is expected because it is taking the data as strings and doing ASCII comparisons, leading to the result that you see.

```
arr1 = "2.0.0.1".split('.')
arr2 = "2.0.0.6".split('.')
```

Compare both `arr1` and `arr2` element by element, for all the data in your input.